# sublist to dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary, sublist

So I have:

```
a = [["Hello", "Bye"], ["Morning", "Night"], ["Cat", "Dog"]]
```

And I want to convert it to a dictionary.

I tried using:

```
i = iter(a)  
b = dict(zip(a[0::2], a[1::2]))
```

But it gave me an error: `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'`

Comment: You want `['Hello', 'Bye']` to be the key for `['Morning', 'Night']`? Because that is what your code tries to do, if it weren't for the fact that lists cannot be keys.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Possibly OP is trying to split the list into keys and values, however OP may think he can treat it as a list of strings disregarding the sublists. That's why he tried `[0::2]` and `[1::2]`

Comment: @jamylak: I *think* Haidro's answer is spot-on, but I am just making sure that the OP didn't perhaps wanted to do what the example code would achieve if it were not for the mutable keys. In which case `dict(zip(map(tuple, a[0::2]), a[1::2]))` would do what the OP wants.

Comment: Yeah sorry I wanted Haidro's answer. I tried using other codes to convert a list to dictionary but I still got that error. Thank you though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Simply:

```
>>> a = [["Hello", "Bye"], ["Morning", "Night"], ["Cat", "Dog"]]
>>> dict(a)
{'Cat': 'Dog', 'Hello': 'Bye', 'Morning': 'Night'}
```

I love python's simplicity

You can see [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict) for all the ways to construct a dictionary:

> To illustrate, the following examples all return a dictionary equal to `{"one": 1, "two": 2, "three": 3}`:

```
>>> a = dict(one=1, two=2, three=3)
>>> b = {'one': 1, 'two': 2, 'three': 3}
>>> c = dict(zip(['one', 'two', 'three'], [1, 2, 3]))
>>> d = dict([('two', 2), ('one', 1), ('three', 3)]) #<-Your case(Key/value pairs)
>>> e = dict({'three': 3, 'one': 1, 'two': 2})
>>> a == b == c == d == e
True
```

Comment: Shortest answer of all time

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try this following code :

```
a = [
    ["Hello", "Bye"],
    ["Morning", "Night"],
    ["Cat", "Dog"]
    ]

b = {}
for x in a:
    b[x[0]] = x[1]
print(b)
```

And if you want your value have more than 1 value (in the form of a list),
you can slightly change the code :

```
b[x[0]] = x[1]
```

to code :

```
b[x[0]] = x[1:]
```

Hope it will help you :)